# Запуск NUnit тестов в VS 2013 и анализ покрытия кода

Tags: visual-studio, юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2013, nunit, codecoverage

Не могу запустить с помощью VS, NUnit тесты. Через ReSharper запускаются, а через VS нет. Установил NUnit Test Adapter (установил в проект с тестами). Но не помогает почему-то. Нужно ли еще какие-то настройки делать ?

вот что пишет лог:

`------ Discover test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in C:\..\Projects\AutocompleteWords\AutocompleteWords.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\AutocompleteWords.Tests.Unit.dll
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,5900008) ==========`

Как можно посмотреть покрытие кода тестами ? Вроде как должна быть вкладка в меню Test в VS но у меня ее нет (есть только Rund, Debug, Playlist, Test Settings), версия VS Professional 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке

> Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in ...

у вас в проекте подключен NUnit3 Beta. Test Adapter поддерживает только стабильную версию NUnit - 2.6.4.

Откатитесь к стабильной версии NUnit. Если ставили вручную - просто скачайте с сайта и замените DLL. Если ставили через NuGet - зайдите в Package Manager и выберите там конкретную версию. Или удалите и поставьте через консоль:

```
Install-Package NUnit -Version 2.6.4
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо, теперь тесты запускаются, а по поводу анализа покрытия кода можете подсказать ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev просто включите его в test settings. Если надо - добавьте в проект новый файл сеттингов, и выберите его в меню как активный.

Comment: на MSDN сказано что требуется Visual Studio Enterprise, это значит что в Visual Studio Professional, такой возможности нет ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev судя по всему, нет.